# Render JSON : nested attributes or different requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, performance, rabl

I am working on a single page application based on angularjs and rails. I use RABL to render JSON files.
A lot of JSON responses need nested attributes like that

```
        child :tags do
        attributes :id, :name
    end

    child webapp.comments do |t|
                     // with other nested attributs like user for comments...
        extends "comments/index"
    end


    child webapp.category do |t|
        attributes :id, :name
    end

    child webapp.user do |t|
        extends 'users/show-lazy'
    end

    node(:image_url) { |webapp| webapp.image_url(:medium) }
```

I have some performance issues because rendering view by RABL take about 800 ms (with one user request!) (Active Record, just 50ms). It is too long. I did not yet activate caching. According to this related issue on Github https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/issues/49, nested attribute can slow down rendering...

My question : If generation of nested attributes take long time, is it better to send different requests like :
get /myresource
get /comments/:id/myresource
get /tags/:id/myresource

What is your opinion ?

Comment: The answer would depend on so many things...how much of the latency is network vs server related, how much data there is, how much control you have over the API, etc. I prefer chunking when I can display something to the user before needing the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If generation of nested attributes take long time, is it better to send different requests?

It depends:

- If the client is going to have to make those requests right away, and speed is a concern, then it would depend on whether all of those requests can get handled before a single request could have been handled. This would depend on the number of servers you have handling requests and whether multiple requests could be handled at once (or almost at once).
- If the client does not need those other resources right away and may not even need them ever, then separate requests would probably be better, but it will influence the design of the client, so you have to take that into consideration.

There are probably other things I missed, but those are two for starters.

Some more things:

- Can you use `include:`/`.includes(...)` or join(s) in your query to reduce n+1?
- Have you also looked at [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) and [ActiveModel::Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) as alternatives to RABL? JBuilder is part of Rails 4 and ActiveModel::Serializers is worked on by some of the core Rails team members.
- Keep an eye on the [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/) project (also in [github](https://github.com/json-api/json-api) where you can provide feedback).
- Take a look at [restful_json](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/restful_json) if you want to avoid a lot of service controller implementation.

Comment: I used include:. Finally, I have decided to switch to ActiveModel::Serializers. My responses speed up from 800 ms to 350 ms !
Unfortunately, cache system does not seem implemented by ActiveModel::Serializers. So, I would take a look at JBuilder !